# PWDENCRYPT in SQL Server 2008 encrypt same data with different result every time why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

I used pwdencrypt to create user of the system i.i saved password by encrypting in sql server 2008.when i try to login i again encrypted the password using pwdencrypt keyword in sql server and found that the encrypted password in sql server was different then recently enter password.to make sure i did this again and found out each tym the encryted result for same password was different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not encrypt your password, it returns a password hash.

You should use [pwdcompare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd822792.aspx) when checking if the password is correct.

Try this:

```
declare @P varbinary(128)
set @P = pwdencrypt('PassWord')

if pwdcompare('PassWrod', @P) = 1
  print 'Yes'
else
  print 'No'

if pwdcompare('PassWord', @P) = 1
  print 'Yes'
else
  print 'No'
```